# Why memory usage keep growing when I repeatedly open and close the same file

Tags: python, linux

Here is the code:

```
while True:
    with open('a', 'w'):
        assert True # just do sth
```

When I run it, the system total memory usage just kept growing.
My 4 core cpu all goes up to 100%.

Why is it happening?

Shouldn't the Linux kernel close fds and free memory immediately ?

My environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 3.13.0-77-generic
- Python 2.7.6
- CPU: Intel Core i3-2350M CPU @ 2.3GHz
- RAM: 7878MiB

Now I can't reproduce the problem too
even running the original code:

```
def main():
    key_list = ""
    for i in xrange(10000000, 1000000000):
        key_list = key_list + str(i) + "\n"
        if len(key_list) > 10000:
            with open("./passwd1.txt", "a+") as f:
                f.write(key_list)
            # del key_list
            key_list = ""
            print "done"
```

Weird...

Comment: Why should it close them _while the script is still running_ ? You might want to use them at a later time.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Which Python version?

Comment: All 4 of your CPU cores reach 100% utilization with a single non-threaded process? Seems like something else is going on here.

Comment: @arkascha The `with` statement ensures the file is closed.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour here, though? If I understand it correctly, this will open the file, assert that `True` is, in fact, `True`, then close the file, an start the loop over. I'm not surprised that endless opening and closing of a file will consume all available system resources.

Comment: @hek2mgl I can reproduce it with python 3.4 on ubuntu. CPU that goes to 100%. I stopped it with ctrl-c before investigating the memory usage, because I didn't want to risk having to reboot if I let the loop run too long.

Comment: Update @hek2mgl Decided to try to run it longer. I can not reproduce the increasing memory usage in either cpython 2.7 or cpython 3.4 . It goes to 100% cpu usage, but memory use stays flat. I wonder if OP's RAM issue could be caused by something else outside the python runtime and the linux filesystem or kernel. Some kind of monitoring process, perhaps?

Comment: Also can't reproduce. also did `import gc` go check garbage collector reference count but it remains unchanged. http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection

Comment: @Renjie Cai: Can you investigate this using `htop` or a similar utility to confirm which process is responsible for the increased memory usage?